# Griddb Get data limited memory

Tags: griddb

- When I have put data on Griddb_nosql sever :
- Data : 1000 row && 10000 column (String data 20 byte),
  But I get data with TQL : " SELECT * " , I see notification:

```
[ 0 ]
1043

[1043:CM_MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED] Memory limit exceeded (name=transactionWork.workerStack, requestedSize=134217744, totalSizeLimit=134217728, freeSizeLimit=1048576, totalSize=5242880, freeSize=0) (address=10.116.41.173:10001, partition=97)
[ 1 ]
1043

[1043:CM_MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED] Memory limit exceeded (name=transactionWork.workerStack, requestedSize=134217744, totalSizeLimit=134217728, freeSizeLimit=1048576, totalSize=5242880, freeSize=0)
```

I can't get all data from Griddb_nosql sever and show to screen. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Error code: [1043:CM_MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED] Memory limit exceeded caused by your transaction of SELECT query which return result with memory exceeded limitation of server.

In your query, I think memory size return is about 200 MB. So, you need to change server setting for transaction memory limitation.

You can refer reference document [here](http://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_3/GridDB_FeaturesReference.html)

Section for changing transaction memory limitation is /transaction/workMemoryLimit

You can try to change value into 500MB. And execute query again.

Notes: I think you should to restart server after change this configuration.